# How do I get my insert function for a binary tree to run for efficiently

Tags: python-3.x

It seems as if my function runs very slowly. It should only take around 10 seconds to insert 100,000 elements, but it actually takes minutes.

Note: rit_object is a private class which puts types for each parameter
    from rit_object import *

```
class EyecuBST(rit_object):

    __slots__ = ('left', 'right', 'parent',
                 'value', 'height', 'size', 'imbalance')
    _types    = ('EyecuBST', 'EyecuBST', 'EyecuBST',
                 int, int, int, int)

def createEyecuBST(el, parent):
    """ creates a BST containing just this node, and connected
    to the given parent node, which is None if this is the root.
    Returns the tree node.
    """
    return EyecuBST(None, None, parent, el, 0, 1, 0)

def eyecuToString(tr):
    """ takes an EyecuBST tree and generates a string containing
    an inorder processing of the nodes of the tree.  For each
    node, the string contains the following information:
    value, height, size, imbalance.
    Returns the string
    """

    if tr == None:
        return ""
    else:
        thisNodeStr = "Value: " + str(tr.value) + ", Height: " + \
        str(tr.height) + ", Size: " + str(tr.size) + ", Imbalance: " + \
        str(tr.imbalance) + "\n"

        return eyecuToString(tr.left) + thisNodeStr + eyecuToString(tr.right)

def insert(tr, el):
    """ function to insert an element into a binary search tree
    following the rules of binary search trees.

    return: an updated tree
    precondition: assumed all elements unique
    """

    if tr == None:
        #print('inserting node root')
        return createEyecuBST(el, None)
        tr.height = 1


    else:
        if tr.value > el: #if node is greater than element
            if tr.left == None:
                tr.left = createEyecuBST(el, tr) #create new node
                #print('inserting node left')
                tr.size += 1 # size of tree + 1
                return tr # return new tree
            else:
                insert(tr.left, el)
                return tr
                if tr.left == None:
                    if tr.right == None:
                        tr.height = 1
                    else:
                        tr.height = tr.right.height + 1
                else:
                    if tr.right == None:
                        tr.height = tr.left.height + 1
                    else:
                        tr.height = max(tr.left.height, tr.right.height) + 1
        else:
            if tr.right == None:
                tr.right = createEyecuBST(el, tr)
                #print('inserting node right')
                tr.size += 1
                return tr
            else:
                insert(tr.right, el)
                return tr
                if tr.right == None:
                    if tr.left == None:
                        tr.height = 1
                    else:
                        tr.height = tr.left.height + 1
                else:
                    if tr.left == None:
                        tr.height = tr.right.height + 1
                    else:
                        tr.height = max(tr.left.height, tr.right.height) + 1

def treeHeight(tr):
    """ 
    Returns the height of the tree rooted at this node. Returns -1
    if input tr is an empty tree (None).
    """

    if tr is None:
        return -1
    else:
        return tr.height


def treeSize(tr):
    """ 
    Returns the size of the tree rooted at target node. Returns 0
    is input tr is an empty tree (None)
    """

    if tr is None:
        return 0
    else:
        return tr.size

def treeImbalance(tr):
    """ 
    Returns the imbalance of the tree rooted at target node. Returns 0
    if input tr is an empty tree (None)
    """

    #if tr is None:
     #   return 0
    #else:


def findNode(tr, val):
    """ finds the target node in the tree.  Returns the node reference.
    Returns None if the node is not in the tree.

    precondtion:  val is non-negative integer.

    """

    # replace with your findNode function code
    return None
```

Any suggestions? I'm trying to get the computation time to speed up. on my insert function, as well as how to keep track of the imbalance.

Comment: 100,000 random elements, or elements at least partially ordered?

Comment: Add prints to the other branches and see if each insert is doing what you expect?

Comment: Yeah I tried. My insert is inserting into the tree correctly, just taking too long.  I have a test function that was given to me and it states the elements are inserted correctly, just the time is surprisingly on large quantities.

Comment: Does it get (much) slower as the tree gets bigger? What are the elements you're inserting? Is the tree (approximately) balanced? (just check the heights of the left and right of the root node, maybe?)

Comment: Yes it gets very slow as the elements get very large. And each element I'm inserting is a random number between 0 and n, where n = a number the user enters. No number is ever used twice.

Comment: What about the height checks? If for some reason you get a degenerate tree that's all down one 'branch', insertion time would be O(size-of-tree) instead of O(log(size-of-tree)). This would happen if you were accidentally adding the same value every time, for instance.

Answer (score 1):

Can you post the whole code? Is your insert function inside of a class? I feel like you did way too much work. I need to see more of your code in order to help you.

Comment: Here's the full program. rit_object changes the class object to what it shows.

Comment: It doesn't include your test code to insert all those numbers. Could you add that too?